# Join with three tables not working properly Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to get data from three tables but giving me wrong results
i am using tables "chairs" , "preBooking" , "usr_booking"

Here is my table "chairs"

```
id      chairNumber     status      vendorId
1       1               2           3018
2       2               1           3018
3       3               2           3018
4       4               1           3018
5       1               1           3020
```

Here is my table "usr_booking"

```
id      chair_number    vendorId        serviceStatus
1       2               3018            1   
2       4               3018            1
```

Here is my table "preBooking"

```
id      userId          vendorId        serviceName         chairNumber         paymentType`    serviceDate
1       123             3018            ABC                 1                   CASH            2020-06-06
```

Now i want to get detail of vendor "3018" (dynamic), I want all chairs (from chairs table) and matching record from "usr_booking"
and "preBooking" table, Here is code which i tried

```
SELECT c.chairNumber
     , c.status chairAvailability
     , pb.chairNumber preBookingchairNumber
     , ub.serviceStatus Bookingavailability
     , ub.serviceName
     , ub.chair_number BookingChairNumber 
  FROM chairs c  
  LEFT 
  JOIN usr_booking ub 
    ON c.chairNumber = ub.chair_number 
  LEFT 
  JOIN preBooking pb 
    ON c.chairNumber = pb.chairNumber 
 WHERE c.vendorId = 3018
 ORDER  
    BY c.chairNumber ASC
```

But showing me wrong result, i am getting following result

```
chairNumber     chairAvailability   preBookingchairNumber   Bookingavailability     serviceName     BookingChairNumber  
1               1                   1                       NULL                    NULL            NULL
1               1                   1                       NULL                    NULL            NULL
2               1                   2                       NULL                    NULL            NULL
3               2                   3                       NULL                    NULL            NULL
4               2                   4                       Inprocess               Hair Cut        4
5               1                   NULL                    NULL                    NULL            NULL
```

"BookingChairNumber" column showing correct data but "preBookingchairNumber" showing wrong result, there should be "1" only
and "chairNumber" is repeating 2 times, where i am wrong ? Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does this mean? --> WHERE c.salon_id = '3018'  can't see salon_id in table chairs. Maybe here are missing some information?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @tboom: that was mistake, updated my question,please tell me where i am wrong ?

Comment: ub.serviceName  is also wrong, serviceName is only available in tablepreBooking.
It would be great if you can provide an MCRE as Strawberry mentioned in the second post.

Comment: I can't reproduce your mistake, i get a different result as you posted. My result is as you described your expected result.

Comment: @tboom: let me try to explain which type of result i want

Comment: @tboom:  From these threee tables i want following results
1)  Chairs -  i want all chairs of vendor =3018
2)   usr_booking  - i want column "bookingchairNumber" =4 ( which is correct in this result)
3)  preBooking - i want column "prebookingchairNumber"  "2","4" in front of chair(chairs table) 2 , 4 

now i can get total chairs , bookingchairNumber,prebookingchairNumber


That's i't